# How to use ffmpeg to copy streams and preserve format and metadata?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two files with multiple streams in each.

Output.mp4 has 2 streams: video and audio (streams 0,1)

Input.mp4 has 3 streams: video, audio and data (streams 0,1,2)

I need to add stream 2 from Input.mp4 to Output.mp4 yielding Final.mov.

I tried using this command but it does seem to preserve the format and metadata for the stream that is added:

```
ffmpeg -y -i Output.mp4 -i Input.mp4 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:2 Final.mov
```

The output from ffmpeg seems to show that it is working but the format and metadata for the streams in the Final.mov is not correct.

I would appreciate any help with how to change the command to make it work.

Thank you!

Here is the command output:

```
ffmpeg -y -i Output.mp4 -i Input.mp4 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:2 Final.mov

ffmpeg version N-84679-gd65b595 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 51.100 / 55. 51.100
  libavcodec     57. 86.103 / 57. 86.103
  libavformat    57. 67.100 / 57. 67.100
  libavdevice    57.  3.101 / 57.  3.101
  libavfilter     6. 78.100 /  6. 78.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-04-15T21:57:13.000000Z
  Duration: 00:24:25.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3571 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 7680x3840 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], 3252 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 100k tbn, 2.15 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-15T21:57:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : HEVC Coding
    Side data:
      stereo3d: 2D
      spherical: equirectangular (0.000000/0.000000/0.000000)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-15T21:57:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-04-12T12:02:32.000000Z
    make            : Insta360
    model           : Insta360 Pro
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    description     : {"info":{"gyro_stabilized":false,"initial_view_changed":false}}
  Duration: 00:24:25.00, start: -0.004233, bitrate: 6394 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv), 7680x3840, 6196 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 360k tbn, 5 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T12:02:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Side data:
      stereo3d: 2D
      spherical: equirectangular (0.000000/0.000000/0.000000)
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 4.0, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T12:02:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #1:2(und): Data: none (camm / 0x6D6D6163), 36 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T12:02:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : CameraMetadataMotionHandler
Output #0, mov, to 'Final.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.67.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 7680x3840 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], q=2-31, 3252 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 100k tbn, 100k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-15T21:57:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : HEVC Coding
    Side data:
      stereo3d: 2D
      spherical: equirectangular (0.000000/0.000000/0.000000)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-15T21:57:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (camm / 0x6D6D6163), 36 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T12:02:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : CameraMetadataMotionHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #1:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov @ 0000000004894f00] Unknown hldr_type for camm / 0x6D6D6163, writing dummy valuesd= 629x
frame= 1465 fps=625 q=-1.0 Lsize=  650825kB time=00:24:24.98 bitrate=3639.3kbits/s speed= 625x
video:581593kB audio:56757kB subtitle:0kB other streams:6602kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.910633%
```

Here are the streams in the Final.mp4 file:

```
ffmpeg -i Final.mov

ffmpeg version N-84679-gd65b595 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 51.100 / 55. 51.100
  libavcodec     57. 86.103 / 57. 86.103
  libavformat    57. 67.100 / 57. 67.100
  libavdevice    57.  3.101 / 57.  3.101
  libavfilter     6. 78.100 /  6. 78.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000002726860] overread end of atom 'stsd' by 2974416 bytes
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Final.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf57.67.100
  Duration: 00:24:25.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3639 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 7680x3840 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], 3252 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 100k tbn, 2.15 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : HEVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (stts / 0x73747473), 36 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't like your stream 1:2 *Unknown hldr_type for camm / 0x6D6D6163, writing dummy values* even though you have specified copy

Comment: Yes. That stream is the GPS data in the video required by Google Street View. Is there someway to work around that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Also had this issue with Sony Videos (h264 and h265 encoded files, stemming from ILCE-7M4): MP4s containing Realtime Metadata (rtmd) which ffmpeg did not allow to copy directly (being super strict). MP4Box does this for you, so you do not necessarily need to "move" your container to MOV or M4V. In the following example I do a 2-pass conversion using Apple's AAC Encoder and a specific bitrate (!= CRF):

```
ffmpeg -y -i "${INPUTFILE}" -c:v libx265 -b:v 35000k -x265-params pass=1 -an -f null /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i "${INPUTFILE}" -c:v libx265 -b:v 35000k -x265-params pass=2 -c:a aac_at -b:a 192k -movflags use_metadata_tags+faststart -map_metadata 0 -tag:v hvc1 "${OUTPUTFILE}"
MP4Box -add ${INPUTFILE}#3 ${OUTPUTFILE}
MP4Box -dump-xml ${INPUTFILE}.xml ${INPUTFILE}
MP4Box -set-meta META -set-xml ${INPUTFILE}.xml ${OUTPUTFILE}
```